# REGEX in Python only matches exponent

Tags: python, regex

I was reading some lines from a file, which I want to match to be floats,
here is a minimal example:

```
import re
regex="[-+]?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?"
string="0.00000000000000000E0   0.00000000000000000E0   0.00000000000000000E0"´
print(re.findall(regex,string))
```

, Which gives me

```
['E0', 'E0', 'E0']
```

Instead of the expected

```
['0.00000000000000000E0', '0.00000000000000000E0', '0.00000000000000000E0']
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the regex to

```
regex=r"[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?"
                  ^          ^^
```

The point is to use a non-capturing group instead of the capturing one so that `findall` did not have to return only the captured text (when there are no capturing groups defined in the pattern, `re.findall` will return whole matched texts).

Also, use a raw string literal always to define regex pattern to avoid any other misunderstanding.

A [Python demo](https://ideone.com/9F06Sn):

```
import re
regex=r"[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?"
string="0.00000000000000000E0   0.00000000000000000E0   0.00000000000000000E0"
print(re.findall(regex,string))
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, consumed more time than it should have :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In case someone else faces the same issue I did, when trying to match "1e-9" I got only "-9". In order to also catch this cases I had to make a slight modification to the regex:
regex=r"[-+]?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?"